# Timeout when routing. Angular 9 Universal + Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular-universal

I'm trying to set up Angular 9 Universal + Firebase application. I've added Universal packages to my project and Firebase cloud function to support SSR. Here is the code of my cloud function:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as path from 'path';

const universal = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/server/main')).app;

export const ssr = functions.runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 }).https.onRequest(universal);
```

My firebase config:

```js
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/browser",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssr"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Build passes without errors and application seems to be working fine but routing doesn't work. Main route (`/`) loads well and I can navigate to other routes without errors but if I try to open any other route (for example `/books`) in a new tab or reload already opened route I'll get timeout exception. Here's the screenshot:
[image: error]

I don't know why do I have this error. I've already tried to increase timeout to 120s but it didn't help. Any advises how can I fix it?

Comment: There's not enough here to root cause this. There must be some missing logs/errors from Angular Universal. I don't know much about this setup; does "app" even return a promise?

Comment: @Kato I get only this error, how can I get more logs?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the scaffolded version of angular universal and you didn't change anything from the server.ts file, you have to pass the *result* of calling your universal function to the `onRequest` function.

So, you would have to change this:

```js
const universal = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/server/main')).app;

export const ssr = functions.runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 }).https.onRequest(universal);
```

To this (you have to call the universal function):

```js
const universal = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/server/main')).app;

export const ssr = functions.runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 }).https.onRequest(universal());
```

Why is this necessary? Your `app` function does not receive any arguments, and returns a `server` object (which is actually an Express-application object). The `onRequest` function receives an anonymous function that receives a `request` and a `response`. So passing the `app` function to `onRequest` doesn't make much sense.

I came across with this exact same problem yesterday, and I really don't know how Firebase is able to serve the root route (/), but not any child route.

Anyway, I hope this answer fixes your problem!

Luciano.